# beautifulsoup find element by dev tools "copy selector"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get element by just using "`Copy > Copy selector`" in chrome dev-tools (f12)

[image: Copy outerHTML"]

And I'm getting:

```
copy_result = "body > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.span10 > div.container-fluid > div > div.span9 > div.public-user-last-active.well.well-nano"
```

What is a faster way to find element by using `copy_result` in the beautifulsoup?

P.S. if you want to help me, I'm looking up: "`Был на сайте:`" 
On this url `"http://teamfinding.com/ru/public/atanvar"`

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    html = requests.get('http://teamfinding.com/ru/public/atanvar')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')
    job_elems = soup.find_all('section', class_='public-user-last-active well well-nano')
    print(job_elems)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct, just change `'section'` in `.find_all()` to `'div'`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    html = requests.get('http://teamfinding.com/ru/public/atanvar')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')
    job_elems = soup.find_all('div', class_='public-user-last-active well well-nano')
    print(job_elems)
```

Prints:

```
[<div class="public-user-last-active well well-nano">
                    Был на сайте: сутки назад                </div>]
```